# Trying DB2 unload using IKJEFT utility

Tags: db2, jcl

I am trying unload:

```
Below is jCL

/STEP90    EXEC PGM=IKJEFT01                             
//STEPLIB  DD DSN=DB2.SYS.LOAD,DISP=SHR                  
//SYSPRINT DD DUMMY,DCB=BLKSIZE=8000                     
//SYSTSPRT DD SYSOUT=*                                   
//SYSDBOUT DD SYSOUT=*                                   
//SYSPUNCH DD DSN=aAA.BAAA.CAAA.DSSSS,         
//         DISP=(,CATLG,UNCATLG),                        
//         UNIT=SYSALLDA,                                
//         SPACE=(CYL,(1000,1000),RLSE),                 
//         DCB=(RECFM=FB,LRECL=800)                      
//SYSTSIN  DD *                                          
  DSN SYSTEM(abcd)                                       
    RUN PROGRAM(DB2pg2) -                               
    PARM('/LRECL=08000')                                 
  END                                                    
/*                                                       
//SYSIN    DD *                                                   
-----------------------------------------------------------       
*                                                                 
SELECT  vAL1    ,'~',                           
       LPAD(EMP_NAME,10,'!')   ,'~',                          
               EMP2_NAME     ,'~',                           
               eMP_ID        ,'~',                           
               DATA_VALUE       ,'~',                           
               GEN_ERR_TEXT       ,'~',                           
               E_TIMESTAMP    ,'~',                           
               E_TEXT_SHORT   ,'~',                           
               E_TEXT_LONG                                    
        from  DB2BATC.ump_error_log where                         
        PROJECT_ID = 'GUI'                                        
  ORDER BY ERROR_TIMESTAMP ASC                                    
  FETCH FIRST 03 ROWS ONLY                                        
   WITH UR;                                                
 */
```

### OUT PUT

```
GUI ~ !!vINAY ~ HKJSKSKS ~ ~ ~ USER NOT PRESEN :
GUI ~ !!KUMARTHA ~ IJKHJHJD ~ ~ ~                             
GUI ~ !!NAUISJSK ~ HJJKSDHSJDHSJ ~ ~ ~ USER NOT EXIST
*************************** Bottom of Data ****************************
```

But i want that to be as :

```
GUI(12 spaces)       ~ !!vINAY              ~ HKJSKSKS              ~ ~ ~ USER NOT PRESEN
```

As vAL1 is defined in DB2 as 15 chars so, what i am expecting is in ps output file

Gui 3 char plus 12 spaces

where as in spuffi i get the same

Answer (score 2):

IKJEFT01 is the TSO monitor program.  You're using it to connect to the DB2 subsystem "abcd" and run application program "DB2pg2".  This is one of the ways to run an application that makes use of DB2 resources.

The output is dependent on the logic in "DB2pg2", so you need to look there.